# undefined method 'charset=' for nil:NilClass in ROR actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I try to send a basic email and ROR return me a stange error :

```
undefined method `charset=' for nil:NilClass
```

my class :

```
class MonitoringAlertMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "myadmin@myadmin.com"    
   def monitoring_alert
            mail( to: 'myemail@email.com',     body: 'test',   content_type: "text/html",    subject: "test")
    end
end
```

errors come from :

```
ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionmailer-5.0.0.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:808:in `mail'


 def mail(headers = {}, &block)
      return message if @_mail_was_called && headers.blank? && !block

      # At the beginning, do not consider class default for content_type
      content_type = headers[:content_type]

      headers = apply_defaults(headers)

      # Apply charset at the beginning so all fields are properly quoted
      message.charset = charset = headers[:charset]
```

where the message object is nil
Note that when I send an email with a testing code it works well

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(
  from: "test@example.co", 
  to: "valid.recipient@domain.com", 
  subject: "Test", 
  body: "Test"
).deliver
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I still got no solution. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 2 days of debugging. 
Upgrading rails from rails', '~> 5.0.0' to 
rails', '~> 5.0.1'